# How to replace column if not null in select statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions

I have a Contact (ID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName).

For example:

```
| ID | FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
|====|===========|==========|============|
| 1  | Mark      |Jordan    | E          |
|----|-----------|----------|------------|
| 2  | James     | Blunt    | NULL       | 
|----|-----------|----------|------------|
```

I want to output

```
Mark E. Jordan
James Blunt
```

So, if MiddleName is not null, add a '.' after, otherwise output null.

I am aware of `isnull` function, however what I need is an `isnotnull` function. How can I finish the query?

My query so far:

```
select FirstName + ' ' + isnull(...)  + LastName
from Contact
```

Answer (score 6):

It's great that a `NULL` plus a value produces a `NULL`*, means you can do stuff like this...

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddleName + '. ', '') + LastName 
FROM Contact;
```

Hopefully, this works for what you want.

* Assuming [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms176056.aspx) is set `ON`, as it should be;

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference is to use [COALESCE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/) as it is ANSI standard.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Contact
    ([ID] int, [FirstName] varchar(5), [LastName] varchar(6), [MiddleName] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO dbo.Contact
    ([ID], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName])
VALUES
    (1, 'Mark', 'Jordan', 'E'),
    (2, 'James', 'Blunt', NULL)
;

--- below both tsql will give you the desired results

set nocount on;
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(COALESCE(FirstName, '') +' '+ COALESCE((MiddleName + '. '), ' ') + COALESCE(LastName, '')))
FROM dbo.Contact

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE(MiddleName + '. ', '') + LastName 
FROM dbo.Contact;
```

> Mark E. Jordan
>
> James  Blunt

Also, just for completeness refer to [If a person's name is Null then how would it break the database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/135645/8783)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CASE to get that reverse logic, but it's easier than that in your case.

```
--With names in separate columns
SELECT FirstName, ISNULL((MiddleName + '.'), '') AS MiddleName, LastName
FROM Contact

--With names merged together, removing any leading/trailing spaces.
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ISNULL((MiddleName + '. '), ' ') + ISNULL(LastName, '')))
FROM Contact
```